# What can be used instead of MockMvc (sprint-mvc-test)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mocking, integration-testing, mockito

I would like to do a test like: http://stevelibonati.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/spring-mvc-test-with-a-sprinkle-of-mockito/

My problem is that I am not allowed to use SNAPSHOTS in this project. Is it possible to achieve this kind og testing (send request object and get the close-to-real response) to e.g do a XML validating....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went on using spring-mvc-test...

Comment: just grab a snapshot (and if its not unique, version it yourself, i.e. spring-mvc-test-20120730), and deploy the fixed version to your 'trusted' repo.

Comment: Mm, just whsat I did. Thanks!

Comment: yw. I successfully got spring-mvc-test working too, it's great!

Answer (score 0):

1.0.0.M is has been released. Check out https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc.

Comment: This package is now part of spring 3.2 RC1